# Can I add a project dependency to a project not in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've created a utility library project which is required by an application project

Unless I add it to the same solution, the only way I can see to create the dependency reference in VS2022 is by pointing at the DLL/EXE assembly on disk in the Reference Manager -> Browse window.

But now I have to explicitly pick the debug/release file and that doesn't seem correct. Do I simply *have* to have them in the same solution or is there another mechanism to describe project-level dependencies instead of assembly dependencies (I assume config files of some type)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a project reference in the project file even if it points to a project that isn't in the solution:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="path/to/UtilityProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

There may be some features in the IDE that don't behave as expected when the project is not included in the solution, though I can't name them off the top of my head.

Another option to try is to add the project to the solution, add the reference, and then create a [Solution Filter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/load-only-the-projects-you-need-with-solution-filters/) (which is like a mask over the solution to exclude certain projects) if you don't want the project open while you're working.